# How to add Content to this Parallax Website?

Tags: html, css, parallax

I downloaded a fire watch parallax template from Codepen and have been trying to add content on top of it.
The parallax works fine, what I need is, to add content (text, images, and so on) after the parallax on the blank space.

I've tried changing the CSS codes and adding Text tags with font color attributes and so on. Nothing has worked.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  
}

.content {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-top: 300px;
  color: black;
}

.parallax {
  background-color: #FEDCC8;
  perspective: 100px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -1500px;
}

.parallax__layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.parallax__layer img {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}

.parallax__cover {
  background: #2D112B;
  color: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 2000px;
  z-index: 2;
}

.parallax__content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.h1 {
  color: #00ff00;
}

.parallax__layer__0 {
  transform: translateZ(-300px) scale(4);
}

.parallax__layer__1 {
  transform: translateZ(-250px) scale(3.5);
}

.parallax__layer__2 {
  transform: translateZ(-200px) scale(3);
}

.parallax__layer__3 {
  transform: translateZ(-150px) scale(2.5);
}

.parallax__layer__4 {
  transform: translateZ(-100px) scale(2);
}

.parallax__layer__5 {
  transform: translateZ(-50px) scale(1.5);
}

.parallax__layer__6 {
  transform: translateZ(0px) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>CodePen - Firewatch Parallax in CSS</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

</head>
<body>

<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<div class="parallax">
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__0">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_0.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_1.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_2.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__3">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_3.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__4">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_4.png?raw=true" />
    </div>

    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__5">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_5.png?raw=true" />
    </div>
    <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__6">
        <img src="https://github.com/samdbeckham/blog/blob/master/dev/_assets/images/articles/firewatch/layer_6.png?raw=true" />
    </div>

    <div class="parallax__cover">
        <
    </div>

    
</div>




<!-- partial -->
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The above is the complete code for the project.
All images are hosted online.

I'm looking to add content after the parallax image on the Purple background. But, whatever I add comes after the background or never shows up.

Answer (score 0):

Add the image as `background-img` in css and add the text in html like below

```
<div class="parallax">
   <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__1">
      <span class="text0>text0</span>
   </div>


   <div class="parallax__layer parallax__layer__2">
      <span class="text>text1</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

background image in css:

```
.parallax__layer parallax__layer__1{
     background-image: url("layer1image.jpg");
  }

  .parallax__layer parallax__layer__2{
     background-image: url("layer2image.jpg");
  }
```

for full understanding view the page source of below mentioned link 
link : https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm